# Detect circular dependencies in project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Last time i found in my project problem with circular dependencies. I resolve my problem but, i would like avoid this in future.
I think about plugin which found circular dependencies in my all project and give me feedback.

Example:

File a.js:

```
var functionFromA= require("./b.js");
console.log("file a", functionFromA);
module.exports = {functionFromA: functionFromA};
```

File b.js:

```
var functionFromB = require("./c.js");
console.log("file b", functionFromB );
module.exports = {functionFromB : functionFromB };
```

File c.js:

```
var functionFromC = require("./a.js");
console.log("file c", functionFromC );
module.exports = {functionFromC : functionFromC }
```

When i run file a.js i see in console:
file c {}
file b { functionFromC: {} }
file a { functionFromB: { functionFromC: {} } }

I found "Circular Dependency Plugin" in npm but i don't know how use it?
May be someone has similar problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can find this other tool useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge

is very easy to use: `madge --circular [directory]` give you a list of circular dependencies in your code located inside `[directory]`. It can also generate a graph image.

Comment: i really love this tool! just solve my problem in few mins

Answer (score 7):

If you have eslint setup, you can add [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import) and enable the `import/no-cycle` rule.

Answer (score 2):

As davidmpaz suggested, **madge** is a good tool for such a thing but it only detects circular dependencies and doesn't indicate whether these circular dependencies causes a problem in your application or not.

I made a tool to detect the circular dependencies and it warns you about the problem that caused by cd.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-circular-deps

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to detect CD during runtime, when we import/require dynamic modules.

Comment: Circular dependencies ALMOST always indicate some poorly thought out application/library structure.  I'd lean toward the `madge` tool since code will usually be clearer if circular dependencies are removed even if they "work".

Comment: Is it possible to make it work on typescript files?

Answer (score 2):

The tool that saved my life was [dpdm](https://github.com/acrazing/dpdm).

One particulary great thing about it, is that it handles mix of typescript and javascript files better than **madge**

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [skott](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skott):

skott is a minimalist developer tool that can be used to efficiently generate directed graphs from your JavaScript/TypeScript/Node.js project. It can run from CLI, for example:

`skott --trackBuiltinDependencies src/index.js`

Read more [**here**](https://github.com/antoine-coulon/skott#readme)

Comment: love the visualization it provides. have an upvote