# How to ensure a module object is initialized once when there are module interdependencies

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have three modules:

```
lib/persons.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({.......});
const personModel = moongoose.model("persons", personSchema);
module.exports = personModel
```

Now there are 2 separate modules (say a.js and b.js) both require persons.js and additionally a.js as well requires b.js.
Because of this, the personModel is getting overwritten which is a mongoose error. If I remove dependency of persons.js from a.js, then the code works (without the requisite functionality).

What is the best way to handle this so that personModel is not overwritten?

Comment: Check for cyclic dependencies in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356204/detect-circular-dependencies-in-project

Comment: "*Because of this, the personModel is getting overwritten*" - no. A module already is initialised only once, no matter how often you require it. This works out of the box, there's nothing you need to do about this.